# Paw hangs when executing a request with Paw HTTP Library

Tags: paw-app

Using Paw 3.1.7

Using Paw HTTP Libary, the request hangs:
[image]

Changing to NSURLConnection or ASIHTTPRequest solves the problem:
[image]

Comment: As clarification, I opened this question as a bug, since Paw doesn't have a public bug tracking system and they are suggesting to use SO.

Comment: Same problem here. Paw HTTP Library is really slow for me, takes minimum 5 seconds to finish a request. "Apple URLSession" or "ASIHTTPRequest" options completes the request in milliseconds.